# Add columns to SPView programatically in a DEFINED order

Tags: 2010

The list has column a,b,f

I want to add some columns to the list and to the view. but in a defined order.  I want column country and organization to be BETWEEN columns b and F

Is it possible?

```
SPList accessList = newSiteCollection.RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Workspace Access Rights");
                    if (accessList != null)
                    {
                        SPFieldCollection collFields = accessList.Fields;
                        collFields.Add("Country", SPFieldType.Text,false);
                        collFields.Add("Organisation", SPFieldType.Text, false);
                        collFields.Add("samAccountName", SPFieldType.Text, false);
                        SPView view = accessList.Views["All Items"];
                        view.ViewFields.Add("Country");
                        view.ViewFields.Add("Organisation");
                    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove all the fields and re-add them again.

Answer (score 0):

Only in SharePoint does a *private implementation detail* of a class, namely of the order in which the fields in this "collection" are stored, have observable effects.

If designed correctly, it would be an SPFieldList that was indexable, and thus explicit that the order mattered. I wish MS would get some decent developers to work on SharePoint.